# EF not updating temporal table from code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

I added properties to my class, created the migration fine. However, when running database update I get the error:

> Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because table 'XXXXX' has 9 columns and table 'XXXXXHistory' has 8 columns.

Is there something I need to add the migration file? Is this a limitation in EF and I need to add the column myself?

I made sure I'm using the latest EF.

EDIT

This can be avoided by making changes to the class one at a time. So, add a new property, create migration, delete a property, create another migration and then update the database.

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: It does seem to be a dupe the linked question, but that question lacks an _accepted_ answer. And that OP gave up on temporal tables all together, meanwhile.

Comment: @Fildor While there was no accepted answer, the correct answer was to make changes one at a time. Apparently there is an issue with EF and  Temporal changes when more than one change, or renaming occurs.